# How to filter RSOP to show only modified policies?

Tags: windows, group-policy, filtering

Is it possible to view only those elements of GPO that are actually modified/specified?

For example, when looking at RSOP for an OU, I have loads of options which are mostly not specified - can I automatically filter it to show only e.g. that it doesn't allow to use control panel or install software, instead of looking through all options?

I am using Win2003 and I have only the default tools.

Thanks in advance!

Sorry for confusion - naturally I didn't mean RSOP, as it shows only the resultant set, i.e. the modified policies. I meant normal gpedit.msc snap-in. And apparently, you can only filter through administrative templates! I thought that it would be possible to filter through security settings as well. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1):

The 'Editing' window of a GPO allows you to 'View' -> 'Filter' and in there is an option to only show settings configured (in that particular GPO) in there. Hopefully this is the same on Server 2003.

Filtering is definitely possible in 2003:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc787811(v=ws.10).aspx

Could you confirm if you have this on a normal GPO? Perhaps it's a limit of RSOP.

Comment: Dan, where is this?  I see the "Settings" tab in the GPMC that does this, but I don't see a `view -> filter`...where is that exactly?

Comment: I am afraid not - in view I have only Add/Remove Columns, Icons size options, DC Options and Customize. And neither of these seems to be the way to go. Which OS are you using?

Comment: I'm a little lost, RSOP and GPRESULTS will only show configured settings. Are you looking at the GPO itself? If that's the case then as Dan says you can filter the view so that you only see configured settings. Right click the GPO and select Edit... then expand Computer Configuration or User Configuration... then right click Administrative Templates... then select the filter option(s). I'm looking at a Windows Server 2008 R2 GPMC and it's slightly different in Windows Server 2003, but it's there.

Comment: @joeqwerty I went and looked at some 2003 screenshots and I think we may have forgotten how basic it was! Looks like old RSOP displayed in an edit-like Window! I'm not 100% on when the view filter appeared, either :(

Comment: @guest I've updated my answer

Comment: @joeqwerty - Ahh...I see that now inside following your directions.  Honestly though, why not just open the GPMC, click the GPO, and in the right window hit the "Settings" tab.  It will show the settings that have been configured.

Comment: @TheCleaner - DUH! Why didn't I think of that. Sometimes the simplest solution evades us. I couldn't see the forest for the trees. Always on your toes!

Comment: Did the settings tab exist in the old console?

Comment: Sorry for confusion - naturally I didn't mean RSOP, as it shows only the resultant set, i.e. the modified policies. I meant normal gpedit.msc snap-in. And apparently, you can only filter through administrative templates! I thought that it would be possible to filter through security settings as well. Thanks for help!

Comment: @Dan - The Settings tab did exist in the Windows Server 2003 GPMC and the filtering options existed as well... somewhere.

Comment: @Dan - no, the settings tab is only available in GPMC.msc

Comment: @guest - If you use the Settings tab (as TheCleaner suggested) you'll see all of the configured settings, not just those configured under Administrative Templates.

Comment: and GPMC.msc is the proper way to mess with GPOs...the gpedit.msc shouldn't be messed with except for local security policies.